# JQuery UI Draggable containment not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("div.con_user").draggable({ 
        delay: 100,
        revert: true,
        containment: $(this).closest(".roomblock_content"), 
        start: function( event, ui) {
            $(this).css("z-index", "200");
        },
        stop: function( event, ui) {
            $(this).css("z-index","50");
        }
    });
```

The containment option for JQuery UI just seems to be broken. Unless I clone div.con_user and reapply the draggable, it doesn't seem to respect the containment option at all.

Could it be due to the fact that I have many .roomblock_content elements in my page, or because my draggable is contained inside a droppable?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot the HTML markup. Here it is:

```
<div class="roomblock_content">
    <div class="roomblock_col1">
        <div class="roomblock_pool_box">
            <span class="roomblock_pool_title"> Pool </span>

            <ul class="roomblock_slots">
                <li>
                    <div class="con_user prepaid_con"> </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="con_user prepaid_con"> </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wrongly setting the containment option of draggable. It should be like below:

```
 containment: ".roomblock_content",
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/JtQKK/)**

Hope this works for you :)